# SQL Query to find effectiveto date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data set:

[image]

and I would like to get this result: 
[image]

```
select c.DHUnitID as ID, UNIT_STAT_CD, DHUnitStatusTypeID, CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(UNIT_STAT_DT as date), 101) as EffectiveFrom,
CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(UNIT_STAT_DT as date), 101) as EffectiveTo
from [Q00HMS_DB001].[PMFUNITS].[PMFUNITS_STATUS_MV] a inner join Q00EDH_DB001.EDH.UnitStatusType b
on a.unit_stat_cd=b.UnitStatusTypeCode inner join Q00EDH_DB001.EDH.Unit c
on a.ID=c.UnitID
where c.DHUnitID='1223'
order by uniT_stat_dt desc
```

I tried in few ways but the EffectiveTo column is not getting the desired results. Any hint in changing the query to get the required result set is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain the logic that you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you GMB for the quick response. Basically when there are multiple statuses, for the EffectiveTo column we would like to take the UNIT_STAT_DT of the next status to show when that status was replaced with the next. Once you reach the last status, then you leave the EffectiveTo column blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [LAG function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This allows you to retrieve the value of a previous row in an ordered partition (the [OVER keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

I recreated your dataset in with a simple table with only the values you provided, and used the following query:

```
select *,
  LAG(EffectiveFrom) over
    (partition by ID order by EFfectiveFrom desc)
  as EffectiveTo
from dbo.PartitionOverDates
order by EffectiveFrom desc
```

Comment: Thanks you Guillaume Cretot-Richert, let me change my query based on your input and will provide feedback soon

Comment: Amazing Guillaume Cretot-Richert, the solution worked perfectly. Thank you and keep up all the good work you are doing.